# Counting the positive integer solutions of an equation

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, mathematics

I have to solve this equation: \$ x + y + xy = n \$

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

long c;

int main()
{
   long x = 0;
   cin >> c;
   if(c == 0)
   {
       cout << 1 << endl;
       return 0;
   }
   for(long i = 1; i <= c / 2; i ++)
   {
       for(long j = 1; j <= c; j ++)
           if(i + j + i * j == c)
           {
                       x ++;
                   break;
           }
   }
   cout << x + 2 << endl;
}
```

Of course this code is very slow. How can I find a positive number of solutions in a faster way? Maybe there is a specific algorithm?

Comment: How do you expect to "solve" that equation? It has an infinite number of solutions, which of the solutions do you want to return?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(Remark: The question mentions *"positive number of solutions"*, but from your code I assume that you meant *"number of non-negative integer solutions"*.)

**Coding style:**

- `#include <cstring>` is not needed here.
- Don't use `namespace std;`, see for example [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).
- `long c;` is only used in `main()`, so there is no need at all to declare it as
  a global variable.
- Always use braces `{ ... }` for the body of for- and if-statements, even
  if it has only one statement. It helps to avoid errors if additional statements 
  are added later.
- Move the computation of the number of solutions to a separate function.
  This keeps the main function small and is convenient if you add test cases.
- I prefer a different spacing in for- and if-statements, but that may be a 
  matter of taste.
- Variable names: If the equation is given as \$ x + y + xy = n \$, then why
  not use the same names in your program? And `x` is a quite non-descriptive
  name of a number of solutions.
- It may not be immediately obvious why `2` is added to the number of solutions,
  so an explaining comment would be appropriate here.

Then your code would look like this:

```
#include <iostream>

// Number of non-negative integer solutions to
//    x + y + x * y == n   .
long numberOfSolutions(long n) {

    if (n == 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    // Count all positive solutions:
    long count = 0;
    for (long x = 1; x <= n / 2; x++) {
        for (long y = 1; y <= n; y++) {
            if (x + y + x * y == n) {
                count++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    // Add 2 for the solutions x=0,y=n and x=0,y=n:
    return count + 2;
}

int main()
{
    long n;

    std::cin >> n;
    std::cout << numberOfSolutions(n) << std::endl;
}
```

**Performance:**

Your code tries all possible combinations of x, y to find solutions
and therefore runs in \$ O(n^2) \$. A small improvement could be to use the
symmetry of the problem, i.e. enumerate only pairs with `x <= y`:

```
for (long x = 1; x <= n / 2; x++) {
    for (long y = x; y <= n; y++) {
        if (x + y + x * y == n) {
            // Counts a 2 solutions if x != y:
            count = count + 1 + (x != y);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This cuts the total number of iterations down by a factor of 2, but it is still
\$ O(n^2) \$.

**Better algorithm:**

If you write your equation as
$$
  n + 1 = x + y + xy + 1 = (x + 1)(y + 1)
$$
then it becomes obvious that it can be solved by determining the
*number of divisors* of \$ n+1 \$. This known as the [Divisor function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function) and can be computed 
efficiently.

Even the simplest implementation

```
long numberOfDivisors(long n) {
    long count = 0;

    for (long j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
        if (n % j == 0) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

runs in \$ O(n) \$ instead of \$ O(n^2) \$. More sophisticated methods use
the prime factorization  of \$ n \$ .